# R concatenating images

Tags: r, image, concatenation

I am trying to select a portion of the top of an image and a portion of the bottom of an image then concatenate the bottom under the top to produce one image.

I have been experimenting with EBImage and have successfully captured the top and the bottom but cannot bring them together.

The following is some test code:

```
library("EBImage")
display(imgcol)

dims <- dim(imgcol)
dims

# top
range <- c(1:round(.185*dims[2]))                          
image.top <- imgcol[round(dims[1]*.25):round(dims[1]*.75),range,]
display(image.top)
dim(image.top)

#bottom
range <- (dims[2]-round(.185*dims[2])):dims[2]
image.bot <- imgcol[round(dims[1]*.25):round(dims[1]*.75),range,]
display(image.bot)
dim(image.bot)

# How do I concatenate images?
# The following creates a large numeric, not a large image
test <- c(image.top,image.bot)
```

Comment: Please consider loading a sample image in your example to make it reproducible for anyone:
`f <- system.file("images", "sample-color.png", package="EBImage"); 
imgcol <- readImage(f)` (replace `;`s by newlines).
You could also improve the readability of your code by avoiding repeating the formula extracting the X-range in array indices:

`xran <- round(dims[1]*.25):round(dims[1]*.75);
yran <- 1:round(.185*dims[2]);
image.top <- imgcol[xran,yran,]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the special case provided in the example when one wants to merge pieces of one and the same image it is actually possible to select parts of the composite image just by using array subsetting `[`, without the need of storing intermediate results and concatenating them. For a generic solution suitable for concatenating image parts of arbitrary origin read on.

```
xran <- round(dims[1]*.25):round(dims[1]*.75)
yran <- c(1:round(.185*dims[2]), (dims[2]-round(.185*dims[2])):dims[2])
imgcol[xran,yran,]
```

Images are represented as multi-dimensional arrays, so you can use `abind` to concatenate them. Specify `along=2` to stack them one on top of the other,

```
library("abind")

imgdat <- abind(image.top, image.bot, along=2)
```

or `along=1` to place them one next to the other.

Currently there is no specific `abind` method defined for Image objects, therefore the output `imgdat` is a plain array. Use `Image` with an appropriate `colorMode` to do the reconstruction.

```
imgnew <- Image(imgdat, colormode=colorMode(imgcol))
```

Another way of achieving this is to use EBImage's function `tile` which operates on an image stack obtained through `combine`. This solution requires, however, that the combined images have the same dimensions.

```
tile(combine(image.top, image.bot), nx=1, lwd=0)
```

The argument `nx=1` specifies that each row will contain only a single image effectively concatenating all frames in a column, and `lwd` sets the padding in pixels between the rows.